# Lost .scss in rails app staging version on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, staging

I'm a rails noob and i have a rails production application on Heroku. 
In order to have more prudent predeployment evaluation I set up a 
staging version using the usual:

```
$ heroku create --remote staging
$ git push staging master
$ heroku run rake db:migrate --remote staging
$ heroku open --remote staging
```

and when i launch the staging app it looks fine except all the css/scss is not running.

what i am overlooking??

Here is my environment.rb file:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Usrochr::Application.initialize!
```

and here is my production.rb file [my staging.rb is the same]:

```
Usrochr::Application.configure do

config.cache_classes = true

config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = false

config.assets.digest = true
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

end
```

Comment: can you please post your `production.rb` and `environment.rb` file

Comment: Here is my environment.rb file:

Comment: where?....by the way check your production.rb that ............`config.serve_static_assets = true` also By default assets:precompile won't process the css/js files in /vendor/assets. In production.rb you can use config.assets.precompile to get additional css/js files processed by the asset precompile`config.assets.precompile += %w[ bootstrap/*.css bootstrap/*.js ]`  Then `rake assets:precompile` will process them and they'll work on heroku.

Comment: Thanks- i tried setting the ..config.serve_static_assets = true  in the staging.rb  file  and no change in the problem with the staging version not showing scss/css.

Comment: please look my comments `config.assets.compile = true`

Comment: As you suggested i ran $ rake assets:precompile  and also set the staging.rb file to config.assets.compile = true and now the staging works fine on heroku!!  Thanks Rajarshi!!!

Comment: can I make a post and can you please vote me up?